# In Data Mining, how to extract the most representative subset from large dataset?

Tags: data-mining

I have a dataset which has 0.35 million rows of data and 23 columns and I want to extract 10000 rows and 23 columns out of it which will best represent the parent data.

Comment: *how to extract the most representative subset from large dataset?* well, that is the biggest question in data-mining, not to mention it depends on many things like, how large the data, how many attributes (column), what kind of data.. such as that.. anyway, your question is opinion based and not related to programming in general.. sorry for the flags.

Comment: @BagusTesa Is this platform only for programming based questions? I don't think so. One can definitely ask ways to do a task. Your response is totally demeaning.

Comment: well, that defeats the purpose of [Stats StackExchange](https://stats.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question is too general. I would suggest few things

1. Use random sub-sampling of data, since you are looking for the most representative set proceed with sampling without replacement. Use cross validation to get the set with maximum accuracy. But understand that the sampling is random.
2. Use stratified sampling- cluster the data into groups. Then sample data points from each groups to make sure more representation of the dataset.
3. Use the entire dataset and to build the model using neural networks. Generally they work with more data.